# Change laravel pagination response object

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, pagination

When I use laravel pagination, I get an object like this:

```
{
    "per_page": 1000,
    "current_page": 2,
    "next_page_url": null,
    "prev_page_url": null,
    "from": null,
    "to": null,
    "data": []
}
```

I would like to add to that object a 'filters' attribute in my controller in order to return in the response what filters has been added. Like this:

```
{
    "per_page": 1000,
    "current_page": 2,
    "next_page_url": null,
    "prev_page_url": null,
    "from": null,
    "to": null,
    "data": [],
    "filters" : []
}
```

When I try to do so in my controller, like

```
$paginated->filters = [ ];
```

It makes no effect, the response object remains the same.

Any ideas ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can get the response array with `toArray()`. Then you can modify it how ever you want.

```
$response = $paginated->toArray();
$response['filters'] = [];
```